# can select() prevent read() from getting interrupted?

Tags: c, select, signals, language-lawyer, posix

According to POSIX, if we use a `select()` to decide when we can use a read without blocking, is it possible that the `read()` is interrupted by a signal and returns `EINTR`?

Comment: Does your question apply to POSIX in general or to a specific operating system? If it is possible according to POSIX (of which I am not sure), then the answer will depend on the operating system.

Comment: POSIX in general.

Comment: Since you have stated in the comments section that your question only applies to the POSIX standard and not to a particular operating system, I have edited your question accordingly and added appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we use a `select()` to decide when we can use a read without blocking, is it possible that the `read()` is interrupted by a signal and returns `EINTR`?

Yes.

I infer that the question is at least in part motivated by the recognition that `read()` indicates `EINTR` only if it is interrupted *before transferring any data*. But "before transferring any data" is not the same thing as "while blocked on data becoming available". As far as the specifications are concerned, the question of whether there is any data available to read, such that a `read()` call would not block, is orthogonal to the question of whether a `read()` call might be interrupted by a signal before transferring any data.

If you are looking for more than that then consider also that `read()` is a cancellation point, so it checks on entry whether there is a pending cancellation request.  Since it does non-trivial work before performing any data transfer, there is necessarily at least a narrow window in which `read()` could receive a signal before it starts transferring data, even when data are already available.

Answer (score 3):

Your reads certainly can be interrupted by signals. All that `select` guarantees is that `read` will not be blocked. It has absolutely nothing to say about possible interruption by signals.

From [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> select() allows a program to monitor multiple file descriptors,
> waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready"
> for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file
> descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a
> corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2), or a sufficiently
> small write(2)) without blocking.

Moreover, how can `select` predict the future? It knows that right now socket has some data which can be read. How can it tell you if signal will be raised when you try to read this data?